# How can I load images as icons dynamically into a TileList using flex?

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, image-gallery, tilelist

Ok, so I have a custom render that I have created:

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
  horizontalAlign="center"
  verticalAlign="middle"
  width="100"
  height="100">
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      [Bindable]
      private var fileLabel:String;

      [Bindable]
      private var fileIcon:Class;

      override public function set data(value:Object):void{
        fileLabel = value.label;
        fileIcon = value.file.url;
      }
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>
  <mx:Image source="{fileIcon}" />
  <mx:Label text="{fileLabel}" />
</mx:VBox>
```

That I want to use for a photo gallery with images that are dragged and dropped onto a TileList. I have that part down, but I can't seem to get the icon thing to work.

Given: value is sort of wrapper for a File class. I want to set the mx:Image source to something that needs to be of type Class. Using nativePath or url gives me a cast error. I see tons of examples online using XML and something like "Embed(/url/to/img.jpg)". I promise you that if you give me one of those examples (using a static image) I will give you a negative vote. THAT IS NOT WHAT IM LOOKING FOR HERE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that this isn't working is because the type of the `fileIcon` property is `Class`. You would generally would only want an object of type `Class` if you plan to use it like a factory, creating instances of that class with it. When you use the `[Embed]` metadata, you are indicating to the compiler that it should embed the specified asset into the SWF and also generate a `Class` to act as a factory for vending object instances that can represent that asset. However, as you had already discovered before posting this question, the problem with `[Embed]` is that you need to hard-code the reference, it doesn't let you supply a value at runtime (because the compiler needs to literally embed the asset, at compile-time).

Fortunately, `mx:Image.source` is a very flexible property that also accepts Strings (despite the fact that most documentation demonstrates using it with embedded assets). As long as the Flex application is capable of loading the asset, you can just supply a String-typed URL as the `source`.

Change the type of `fileIcon` to a String, and also verify that `value.file.url` is actually a URL of an image that your application can load. (You can test this just by hardcoding this URL into the `mx:Image`'s `source` attribute.)

Comment: Hey Erik, thanks so much!!

I'm new to flex so learning the framework is my major hurdle. And I'm used to people named "Vishnu" or "Sandeep" (A generalization.. i'm kidding) reply to my tech questions on other sites with useless information, or just repeating things I said in my original post.